# Bring in a variable into a SQL statement with CGI Python

Tags: python, cgi, mysql-python

All I want to do is do an update statement and bring in two cgi python variables: inputMin, and inputMax.

Here's what I have:

```
curInsert.execute("Update User set SetMinF = %d, SetMaxF = %d" .format(inputMin, inputMax))
```

What's the proper syntax to bring in a variable? `%d`? `%s`? `?`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, it was something dumb. I was using floats and needed %f, so it looks like this:

```
curInsert.execute("Update User set SetMinF = %f, SetMaxF = %f" % (inputMin, inputMax))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `curInsert.execute("Update User set SetMinF = %s, SetMaxF = %s" % (inputMin, inputMax))`